# How to view the read and write from the application

Tags: opensuse

I won't sudo the application I am using, as I do not trust it. But it is still able to read and write to the files in the /home/{username} when I run it.

How can I see what files the application is reading and writing?

Answer (score 5):

You can view the `read()` and `write()` calls made by an application by using `strace`:

```
strace -f -e read,write <executable>   # Launch new process, or
strace -f -e read,write -p <pid>       # Attach to existing process
```

You can also see what file descriptors it currently has by looking at `/proc/<pid>/fd`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 chris chris 64 Dec 23 12:46 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 chris chris 64 Dec 23 12:47 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 chris chris 64 Dec 23 12:47 10 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 chris chris 64 Dec 23 12:47 2 -> /dev/pts/3
```